# Is iTunes search API working correctly?

Tags: itunes, itunes-sdk, itunes-api

I’m trying to search all film with word “Seven”. It found 50 films. But some films and its description does not contain word “Seven”. For example film with trackId = 421072264 not contain word “Seven”.

Is iTunes search API working correctly?

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Seven&entity=movie
```

I attached response to Search%3DSeven.txt file.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55328092/Search%3DSeven.txt

Comment: It looks like the ones that aren't matched, match the numerical value `7`, for example: `{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"feature-movie", "trackId":458345365, "artistName":"Daniel Grou", "trackName":"7 Days", "trackCensoredName":"7 Days"...`

Comment: The result you highlight is the **_seventh_** Harry Potter movie, which may hint that the search engine looking into other data, than what is presented to you in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is working correctly, the search defaults to a broader set of data to search on when no attribute parameter is specified in the query.

You can reduce the search parameters by setting a value for attribute the the query, however this will still not stop it from returning films with 7 in their title, this seem to just be a quirk of the search algorithm.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Seven&entity=movie&attribute=movieTerm
```

Weirdly this returns "Fast & Furious 5 - 7 Collection" before "Seven" which doesn't make much sense.

If it needs to be more precise then a id search can be done which would only return the specified movie

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=534912090
```

See this link for more details on how to modify the search query and lookup searches: 
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching